# How to create a snowflake animation scene without using nth-child for each element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-animations

Is there a way to write the CSS code without using all the `nth-child()` selectors? I want to make the code more scalable in case I want to add more snowflakes in the future.

```css
body {
 background-color: red;
}
.snowflake {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes snowflakes-fall {
  0% {
    top: -10%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes snowflakes-shake {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
    transform: translateX(80px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes snowflakes-fall {
  0% {
    top: -10%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes snowflakes-shake {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(80px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.snowflake {
  position: fixed;
  top: -10%;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-animation-name: snowflakes-fall, snowflakes-shake;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s, 3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite, infinite;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running, running;
  animation-name: snowflakes-fall, snowflakes-shake;
  animation-duration: 10s, 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite, infinite;
  animation-play-state: running, running;
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(0) {
  left: 1%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s, 0s;
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 10%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s, 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s, 1s;
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 20%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s, 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 6s, 0.5s;
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 30%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s, 2s;
  animation-delay: 4s, 2s;
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(4) {
  left: 40%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s, 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s, 2s;
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s, 3s;
  animation-delay: 8s, 3s;
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(6) {
  left: 60%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s, 2s;
  animation-delay: 6s, 2s;
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(7) {
  left: 70%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s, 1s;
  animation-delay: 2.5s, 1s;
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(8) {
  left: 80%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s, 0s;
  animation-delay: 1s, 0s;
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(9) {
  left: 90%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s, 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 3s, 1.5s;
}
/* Demo Purpose Only*/
.demo {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.demo a {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
 <div class="snowflakes" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="snowflake">❅</div>
      <div class="snowflake">❅</div>
      <div class="snowflake">❆</div>
      <div class="snowflake">❄</div>
      <div class="snowflake">❅</div>
      <div class="snowflake">❆</div>
      <div class="snowflake">❄</div>
      <div class="snowflake">❅</div>
      <div class="snowflake">❆</div>
      <div class="snowflake">❄</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That’s the whole point of LESS/SASS: using mixins to reduce code redundancy.

Comment: @Terry I know, but I want to do it in CSS if possible

Comment: Have you explored CSS variables?

Comment: Preprocessors aren't much use anyway here because the code is still there, just appearing after compile rather than during write-time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start by removing all the non needed prefixes and the default values. Then in such situation you can use inline styles combined with CSS variables to add the specific CSS. I have also updated the code a little to use flexbox and get rid of all the left values:

```css
.snowflakes {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 9999;
  pointer-events:none;
}
.snowflake {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: -10%;
  animation: snowflakes-fall 10s linear, snowflakes-shake 3s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: var(--d);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes snowflakes-fall {
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes snowflakes-shake {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(80px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="snowflakes" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="snowflake" style="--d: 0s, 0s;">❅</div>
  <div class="snowflake" style="--d: 1s, 1s;">❅</div>
  <div class="snowflake" style="--d: 6s, 0.5s;">❆</div>
  <div class="snowflake" style="--d: 4s, 2s;">❄</div>
  <div class="snowflake" style="--d: 2s, 2s;">❅</div>
  <div class="snowflake" style="--d: 8s, 3s;">❆</div>
  <div class="snowflake" style="--d: 6s, 2s;">❄</div>
  <div class="snowflake" style="--d: 2.5s, 1s;">❅</div>
  <div class="snowflake" style="--d: 1s, 0s;">❆</div>
  <div class="snowflake" style="--d: 3s, 1.5s;">❄</div>
</div>
```

Comment: beautiful - hope you don't mind my edit.. ;)